# Add Javascript function in JavaFx2

Tags: javafx-2

I loaded the html file in webview in javafx2. We can call the javascript function by `webEngine.executeScript("functionName()")` if the function name is already available in the loaded HTML file.

Now I need to add external javascript file / function into the page. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use InputStream to read the external File from URLConnection then add content of stream to StringBuilder then keep them in executeScript . I think this way it will work.